# What's the canonical way for a Razor page to wait for a Blazor component to finish rendering?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

Razor components and pages both have an `OnAfterRender` lifecycle method. When you have `<SomeComponent>` in your `index.razor`, the `index.razor`'s `OnAfterRender` fires first, and then the `SomeComponent.OnAfterRender` fires afterwards.

Suppose on the razor page you need to do some work, but can only do it after `SomeComponent.OnAfterRender` fires. What's the appropriate way to do that?

This can be important because a component's backing HTML is not ready (may not exist) until its `OnAfterRender` fires. So in other words, how can a razor page author know when its components are the equivalent of DOM ready?

Comment: The parent shouldn't be working on the generated markup of any of its children's content. The child component itself should do it. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @PeterMorris Imagine a Blazor component that's a Diagram or Charting library, where you add the <Chart> to your page, then want to set it up with data or query it (maybe its size or color) when its ready. It's possible I'm mistaken about how such a component should be authored, or that component authors should add some kind of loading event, but I expected Blazor components to have their own version of "ready" in this way.

Comment: Why would the chart need to know when the other components have rendered?

Comment: It wouldn't, the page that contains the chart may need to know when the chart has rendered, or is capable of rendering something, etc.

Comment: The rendering should be perceived to be instant. If this is not the case then you need to speed up the rendering. Is this the real use case?

Comment: The real use case is developing a Component that has a <canvas> it manipulates, and wanting to use that component in a page. So I can add the component, then try to do stuff with it during the page `OnAfterRender`, but since the component's `OnAfterRender` has yet to fire, the canvas (all of its DOM) does not yet exist, and methods that attempt to manipulate it will fail. I can get around this by making the component a `Load` event, but I was wondering if there's a more canonical way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could have your child component expose an `Action` parameter which it executes after it has rendered, like so.

```
[Parameter]
public Action AfterRender { get; set; }

protected override OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
  Action?.Invoke();
}
```

In the parent

```
<MyChild AfterRender=@SomeMethodInParentComponent/>
```

I suggest `Action` instead of `EventCallback` because of the following process that I suspect might occurr

1. After EventCallback, Blazor calls StateHasChanged on the callee (the parent)
2. The parent re-renders
3. The parent sets parameters on the child (the `AfterRender` parameter we created)
4. In case any of the state of the parameters has changed, the child will re-render
5. Your child component's `OnAfterRender` method will invoke its `AfterRender` parameter
6. Repeat step 1

Using an `Action` instead of an`EventCallback` will avoid that situation.

However, if you are passing other parameter values (that might change) from the parent to the child then you should use EventCallback. In this case you'll need to override `ShouldRender` in your child component so it only renders when the state it works for has actually changed.

You can check if the state has changed by overriding `SetParametersAsync` and do something like this.

```
private bool NeedsRendering = true; // Always true for first render

protected override bool ShouldRender => NeedsRendering; // Render only if we say so

protected override void SetParameters(ParameterView parameters)
{
  string oldProperty1 = Property1;
  byte oldSomethingElse = SomethingElse;

  base.SetParameters(parameters);

  if (oldProperty1 != Property1 || oldSomethingElse != somethingElse)
  {
    NeedsRendering = true;
  }
}

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync()
{
  NeedsRendering = false; // We are up to do, not more renders until state changes
  // Do your other stuff
  AfterRender?.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very comprehensive.

Comment: Just on a side note, if you need to do async stuff in that event handler, use a Func<Task> instead of the Action and call and await it in OnAfterRenderAsync()